# bazel linkshared option creates a large shared library

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, bazel

I'm using bazel to build a shared libary, but the output so file size is much bigger than expected; For comparision I also build a binary with same deps and srcs in BUILD file, the binary ouput size is much smaller;  Code sample:

```
cc_binary(
   name = "server",
   srcs = ["server.cc"],
   deps = [...]
)  # the binary

cc_binary(
   name = "libs.so",
   srcs = ["server.cc"],
   deps = [...],
   linkshared = 1
)   # the shared library
```

`libs.so` is about 5 times larger than `server`;  It seems linkshared option packs all symbols in `deps` to the shared library, including unused functions, variables(`nm` shows `libs.so` contains much more symbols than `server`);  How can I just link needed symbols to my shared library?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're compiling a shared library, there is no such thing as "unused functions". You're creating a library with functions that an executable can use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; Finally  I figured out the reason: linkshared=1 changes linker behavior by taking all object files as  '--whole-archive'  in -2.params file;  I manually link my shared library, specifing whole/no-whole archive as needed for every object file ;